# process multi-line data as a single record

Tags: python

This code is working as expected and returns the date.

```
str='Date : {{2014,8,7},{8,48,48}} :: Connected to ["280",46,"179",46,"67",46,"194",58,"2345"]'

a = str.split(':')[1].split(',')[0][-4:]+'-'+str.split(':')[1].split(',')[1].zfill(2)+'-'+str.split(':')[1].split(',')[2].replace('}', '').zfill(2)

import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

(Is there an easy way to extract date+time?)

I have the same string in a text file on 2 lines.

```
Date : {{2014,8,7},{8,48,48}} ::  
     Connected to ["280",46,"179",46,"67",46,"194",58,"2345"]
```

How do I process both the lines as a single record?
It can span to 3 lines like this:

```
Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,49}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},
                                                        {queue_file,
                                                         "./sample_esme.dqueue"}]
```

I can't process the file line by line, because there would be no way to link the datestamp with the connected server or Queue initialized.

Comment: Just put it in list until you find line starting with "Date" then use `"".join(list)` to generate string and process it.

Comment: Please don't use `str` as a variable name. It's confusing and can lead to subtle bugs because it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: You can try using regex for extracting the date. Splitting seems very cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract datetime, you can use regex:

```
str='Date : {{2014,8,7},{8,48,48}} :: Connected to ["280",46,"179",46,"67",46,"194",58,"2345"]'

import re, datetime
regex = re.compile('Date\s*:\s*\{(?P<val>.+)\}')
s = re.search(regex,str).group('val')
print datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '{%Y,%m,%d},{%H,%M,%S}')
```

Output:

```
2014-08-07 08:48:48
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
l = list() 
for line in text: 
    if line.startswith('Date') and l:
        multiline = "".join(l)
        **some processing**        
        l = list()
    l.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator that joins lines that begin with a space. Something like this:

```
def join_start_with_whitespace(it):
    cur = []

    for line in it:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            cur.append(line.strip())
        elif line:
            if cur: yield ''.join(cur)
            cur = [line.strip()]
    if cur: yield ''.join(cur)
```

Demo:

```
data = '''
Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,49}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},
                                                        {queue_file,
                                                         "./sample_esme.dqueue"}]
Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,50}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},
                                                        {queue_file,
                                                         "./sample_esme.dqueue"}]
Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,51}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},
                                                        {queue_file,
                                                         "./sample_esme.dqueue"}]
'''.split('\n')

print(list(join_start_with_whitespace(data)))
```

Output:

```
['Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,49}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},{queue_file,"./sample_esme.dqueue"}]',
 'Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,50}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},{queue_file,"./sample_esme.dqueue"}]',
 'Date : {{2014,8,7},{11,6,51}} :: Queue initailized !!! [{rps,30},{queue_file,"./sample_esme.dqueue"}]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the re module. If the line matches the date pattern, it will return a non-empty list. Without giving you the full solution, I am telling you how to do this easily with re.

Once you concatenate the 3 lines into 1 as suggested in another answer:

```
import re
>>> re.findall(r'^.*{{(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)},.*$', line)
[('2014', '8', '7')]

>>> mydate = re.findall(r'^.*{{(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)},.*$', line)
>>> '-'.join(mydate[0])
'2014-8-7'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex might be a better option.
I am giving an example.

```
import re

s = """Date : {{2014,8,7},{8,48,48}} ::  Connected to ["280",46,"179",46,"67",46,"194",58,"2345"]"""

m = re.match(r"^Date : {{(?P<year>\d+),(?P<month>\d+),(?P<date>\d+)},{8,48,48}}", s)

print m.group('year')
print m.group('month')
print m.group('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if the file size (test1.txt) is small enough.

```
inner=''
mylist=[]
final=[]

for line in open('test1.txt', 'r'): 
    inner += line 
    mylist=inner.split('Date :')

for item in mylist:
    str=item.split('::')[0]
    try:
        import re, datetime
        regex = re.compile('\{(?P<val>.+)\}')
        s = re.search(regex,str).group('val')
        myd=datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '{%Y,%m,%d},{%H,%M,%S}')
        final.append((myd, item.split('::')[1]))
    except:
        pass

import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='dba', passwd='dba', db='test')
cur = conn.cursor()
query="""INSERT INTO logs  (mydate, mytext) VALUES (%s, %s) """    
cur.executemany(query, final)
conn.commit()
```